# Java JPA Realtions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am doing an application where I need 2 entities: User and Car.

```
    public class User{
        private long id;
        private String name;
    }

    public class Car{
        private long id;
        private User firstUser;
        private User secondUser;
    }
```

So my table cars_info info will contain
RENT(date), FIRST_USER(id), SECOND_USER(id)

How do I connect this using hibernate? I need unidirectional relation. I tried OneToOne, ManyToOne but neither of that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you're properly naming the column on your CAR table vs the reference column on the USER table. Example below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CAR")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CAR_ID")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FIRST_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    private User firstUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SECOND_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
    private User secondUser;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is exactly what i've been looking for, it works now.